# RPi not booting from SD Card

Tags: boot, sd-card

I have a weird example.
My SD card was working perfectly fine until i wanted to change disty on it.
It says image is loaded successfully, but not booting at all.
I tried a 1GB SD card to test and that card is booting fine.
Is there any chance to fix other card, it's an 8GB SanDisk SD card?

Comment: you could try redownloading the image and reburning it. You could also try copying the image from the working card to your desktop and then burn that image.

Comment: i have tried several images. All won't boot. Even the same one i loaded into 1GB card won't boot in 8GB card.

Answer (score 1):

Try with multiple SD cards with multiple distros. If another SD card does not work, your RPi may be damaged. If another card works, well your SD card is working. I highly doubt your RPi is the problem, since there was a problem with one SD card not another.

Comment: SD card works fine in PC, just doesn't boot in RPi.
Is it possible boot sector is damaged?

Comment: Maybe, seeing that it works with a 1 GB SD card, you are able to acccess the files on a computer but not on a RPi. However, did you check the file format you are using? (exFAT, FAT 32, etc.)